# Mongo, use totalmilliseconds in linq query

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following linq function:

```
TimeSpan lInterval = aEndTime - aBeginTime;
int lIntervalInt = (int)Math.Round(lInterval.TotalMilliseconds/(30*60*1000));

var meh = lCollection.Aggregate()
            .Match(lValue => lValue.Tag == LTag._id)
            .Match(lValue => lValue.TimeStamp >= aBeginTime)
            .Match(lValue => lValue.TimeStamp <= aEndTime)
            .Group(lValue => new {Period = (lValue.TimeStamp-aBeginTime).TotalMilliseconds/lIntervalInt, TimeStamp = lValue.TimeStamp }, g =>
                new
                {
                    Key = g.Key,
                    avgValue = g.Average(x => x.Value)
                })
            .Project(r => new cValueDouble()
            {
                TimeStamp = r.Key.TimeStamp,
                Tag = LTag._id,
                Value = r.avgValue
            });
```

My collection looks as follows:

```
ObjectId _id;
DateTime TimeStamp;
ObjectId Tag;
double Value;
```

What I am trying to do is to aggregate the values via specific user defined time interval. The values are for example logged every two minutes, but I want to retrieve the data as averaged over 30 minutes.
But the problem looks like that the mongo driver doesn't support the `timespan.TotalMilliseconds` command. I get the following error when trying to run the code:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in MongoDB.Driver.dll
>
> Additional information: Member TotalMilliseconds of type System.TimeSpan in the expression tree ({document}{TimeStamp} - 1/1/2010 12:00:00 AM).TotalMilliseconds cannot be translated.

Is there another command I can try to do this? Or perhaps a totally different approach. I would prefer to do the aggregation in mongo and not locally on the machine.

EDIT
Is there not someway I can convert the mongo document timestamp to somekind of timeish format. I only need to have a constant reference to a time period.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because it is a TimeSpan type object which Mongo doesn't understand. Try converting this to a double first before using in your query and it should work...

As a side note: Why are your variables prefixed with 'l' or 'a'? I see this sometimes and cannot understand the reasoning

Comment: How do I convert it to a double before hand? I need to calculate what that specific document's timestamp is. Will a cast to double just work there?

Comment: On the sidenote, the prefixes denote where the variable comes from, l = locally declared, a = argument. Its a coding standard and it makes it easier to code as well as read the code.